# Не компилируется простая библиотека

Tags: gcc, boost, cmake, mingw, makefile

Хочу скомпилировать эту библиотеку в dll, но или я тупой или что-то не работает.

https://github.com/nathan-osman/win32pe

Скачал boost, cmake-gui, mingw последней версии, добавил в cmake атрибут BOOST_ROOT=boost-xx (папка в архиве с сайта boost для win32), добавил в PATH системы папку mingw32/bin, нажал configure и generate, всё получилось, cmake сработал.

Дальше открываю окно команд в папке, которая была выбрана для build и пишу там mingw32-make.exe. И появляется такая чушь:

```
C:\win32pebuild>mingw32-make.exe
[ 16%] Building CXX object win32pe/CMakeFiles/win32pe.dir/src/file.cpp.obj
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:45:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 i386  = 0x014c,
 ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:45:9: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:45:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 In file included from C:\win32pe\win32pe\src\file_p.h:32:0,
                 from C:\win32pe\win32pe\src\file.cpp:32:
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:64:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
 FileHeader();
            ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:65:16: error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'
 FileHeader(const FileHeader &other);
            ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:65:16: error: expected ')' before 'const'
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:66:25: error: declaration of '~win32pe::FileHeader' as non-member
 virtual ~FileHeader();
                     ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:68:50: error: 'win32pe::FileHeader& win32pe::operator=(const win32pe::FileHeader&)' must be a nonstatic member function
 FileHeader &operator=(const FileHeader &other);
                                              ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:70:24: error: non-member function 'uint16_t win32pe::machine()' cannot have cv-qualifier
 uint16_t machine() const;
                    ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:71:30: error: non-member function 'uint32_t win32pe::timeDateStamp()' cannot have cv-qualifier
 uint32_t timeDateStamp() const;
                          ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:72:32: error: non-member function 'uint16_t win32pe::characteristics()' cannot have cv-qualifier
 uint16_t characteristics() const;
                            ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:74:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private'
 private:
 ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:78:5: error: 'friend' used outside of class
 friend class FilePrivate;
 ^
C:/win32pe/win32pe/include/win32pe/fileheader.h:81:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^
win32pe\CMakeFiles\win32pe.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'win32pe/CMakeFiles/win32pe.dir/src/file.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [win32pe/CMakeFiles/win32pe.dir/src/file.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:92: recipe for target 'win32pe/CMakeFiles/win32pe.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [win32pe/CMakeFiles/win32pe.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:128: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2

C:\win32pebuild>
```

На ubuntu всё в порядке, но я компилирую программу для windows, которой нужен dll, поэтому мне надо что-то с этим сделать. Что за бред мне написало?

Comment: ты приложение то собрал? cmake

Comment: Программу ещё нет, я вот пытаюсь собрать библиотеку которая используется в этой программе. Cmake сконфигурировал и сгенерировал её (библиотеку), а make выдаёт ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я уже писал в твоей теме на ЛОРе, проблема в том, что gcc при компиляции под 32х-разрядный x86 (не важно под какую ОС) определяет макрос `i386`, а в коде этот же идентификатор используется для определения константы.

Фикс тут: https://github.com/nathan-osman/win32pe/pull/1

Comment: Спасибо, помогло сразу

Answer (score 0):

1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
4. make
5. иногда нужно еще раз make

Возможно буст еще так не подключить так как в репозиторе там видно что человек с unix собирает. Нужно добавить

```
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

Comment: соответственно папку build в корневой папке с библиотекой

Comment: У меня windows а не linux, mingw32-make.exe а не make. Я делал всё тоже самое, только build снаружи был в другой папке. И как это вообще связано с теми ошибками? Там что-то про синтаксис написано

Comment: Ну не собрал он у вас cmake ом. Что выдает семейк напишите.

Comment: @Debugger55 как собирали cmake ? Без ключа ?

Comment: С BOOST_ROOT=boostfolder и CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=i386 собирал, configure и generate, а дальше уже запускал make и эти ошибки появились

Comment: Cmake выдавал что всё успешно

Comment: Как выбрать boost_filesystem? Нигде не могу найти

Comment: Кажется я понял в чём проблема, неправильно boost указал, хотя он пропустил почему-то эту ошибку (cmake). Щас буду разбираться как его устанавливать

Comment: Не получилось, выдаёт те же ошибки. Я в недоумении, что за ***

Comment: Помогите кто нибудь заставить работать это уродство, я скоро сдамся